# Why does $\tan(z)$ have a non-isolated singularity when z tends to infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

My professor told me that there's a non-isolated singularity of $\tan(z)$ as $z$ tends to infinity.  However, I'm wondering why is this the case, since for $\tan(z)$ to have a singularity, $\cos(z)=0,$ which definitely are isolated singularities.

Comment: $\cos(z)=0$ when $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$, and these points accumulate at $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @carmichael561 is there another way to look at this? I never learnt Riemann sphere.

Comment: Map $z\to\frac{1}{z}$, and note that the points $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi}$ converge to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at this is to note that the behavior of a function $f: \bar{\mathbb C}  \to \bar{\mathbb C}$ as $z \to \infty$ is equivalent to considering $g(z) = f(1/z)$ as $z \to 0$.  For $f(z) = \tan z$, even just along the line $\Im(z) = 0$ we have singularities of $g$ whenever $z \in S = \left\{( \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi)^{-1} : k \in \mathbb Z\right\}$.  But clearly, for any sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, there is always some $w$ satisfying $-\epsilon < w < \epsilon$ such that $w \in S$; i.e., no matter how small a radius we draw around the point $z = 0$, we can find a singularity of $g$ in that neighborhood.  This means the singularity at $0$ is not isolated, and the corresponding singularity of $f$ at $\infty$ is not isolated.

Comment: In general, this same argument implies that if a function has a singularity at $\infty$, that singularity is isolated iff all other singularities are contained within some unit disc of finite radius $R$.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that what your teacher told you is that

1. $\tan$ has a singularity at $\infty$;
2. that singularity is not isolated.

The fact that it is not isolated is a consequence of the fact that $\tan$ has singularities at all the points of the form $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$).

Comment: The teacher really meant $\tan(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$ as the quotient of two entire functions is meromorphic, so $\tan(1/z)$ is meromorphic on $|z| > 0$ but not at  $z=0$ where its poles accumulate

Comment: @reuns I don't understand the purpose of your comment.

Comment: Then read it again. The OP asked what means "$\tan(z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at $\infty$"

Comment: @reuns That is just plain **false**. Your quotation does *not* appear at the OP question. He did *not* write “at $\infty$”; instead, he wrote “as $z$ tends to infinity” and I tried to explain what that meant.

Comment: But you didn't explain why we are interested in this. If $f(1/z)$ had an isolated singularity at $z=0$ we could write its Laurent series converging for $0 < |z| < r$ obtaining a Laurent expansion at $\infty$ for $f(z)$.

Comment: @reuns Indeed, I did not explain why we are interested in this. And the OP did not ask for it. He asked for the *meaning* of the expression. And I explained it.

Comment: We are discussing of the best way to teach a certain tool/concept. That $\tan(z)$ has poles at $\pi (\mathbb{Z}+1/2)$ fits into a comment.